# Large MySQL InnoDB table - Fast LIKE queries

Tags: mysql, innodb

I've got a large (1 million+ rows) MySQL InnoDB table with the following columns:

```
id int(11)
name varchar(255)
```

If I perform the following query it takes a very long time (Well over 3 minutes [I got bored whilst waiting and stopped it]).

```
SELECT name FROM large_table WHERE name LIKE '%peter%'
```

I have added an index on the `name` column which has made it perform much better **0.009 seconds**

I just want to confirm that this is this a suitable work-around for the issue? Or are you reading this cringing?

Comment: I'm a novice at optimization, but I'm surprised an index on an innodb table improved your LIKE query... I would have suggested a MySQL table with a fulltext index and using a fulltext search http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html

Comment: I'm surprised too, I thought `LIKE` queries starting with `%` defeated the index and always resulted in a table scan!

Comment: Don't forget that MySQL has an efficient cache.  You MIGHT be getting an amazing performance boost simply because it already knows how to find name like '%peter%'  Rely more on explain plan, and make sure to change up your search conditions regularly when trying to optimize queries.

Comment: I would also suggest a fulltext index.

Comment: Thanks guys. I have tried a lot of different queries to ensure it isn't being cached and, as you all have said, surprisingly it has made a difference. The reason I didn't initially chose a full text search is because I need partial word matching. I suppose in an ideal world I would implement something like Sphinx however due to project deadlines I do not have time to do that. Thank you all for your help.

Comment: It's also possible that the search is fast because your table is heavily fragmented.  When you created the index, the contents of that index are all in once place on disk.  The query then searches the index instead of the table and since it is all stored sequentially it is able to read the index into memory much faster.  You might find that as you insert more records and the index becomes fragmented that the performance starts to drop.